# A substitute for render(controller())

Tags: symfony

actually in my project I need to display in the navbar if the user have requests. To do this I use in the twig template a:

```
{{ render(controller("AppBundle:TeamRequest:numberRequests")) }}
```

The controller is very simple, just do a doctrine request, and generate a view.

But this part of code is slow... It take 200ms more than if I disable it.

Is there a better way to do this ?

PS: Someone know what is the Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListerner\ProfilerListener ? Because it's this part that take a lot of time in the main and subrequest.

Thanks a lot :-)

Thanks to the answers, the idea is to do a service. In my case, I don't change it, because as you can see in graph, the main part of the time is for the debugbar, finally, it takes few ms to generate it.

All the Timeline (Threshold: 50ms)
[image]

Only the subrequest Timeline (Threshold: 1ms)
[image]

Comment: Did you try to run request in production mode? ProfilerListener like name suggests is for profiling application in development mode, and in production mode is not used.
You can verify this by running: 
```console debug:event-dispatcher --env=dev | grep Profiler```
```console debug:event-dispatcher --env=prod | grep Profiler```

Comment: Exact, it's a listener for the web debug toolbar, I had a doubt. It means finally do a render(controller()) just take 15 ms.

Comment: That is because it's subrequest, symfony will create another request, it will load again whole framework and process request, this will take lot of time especially in dev environment. You can avoid this like guys bellow suggest . But you will loose ability to cache your request with ESI.

Comment: Yes, but finally I think it's not really a problem, as you can see on the screenshot, on 208ms there is 193ms for the ProfilerListener, that mean say use it is not too expensive. The other symfony parts are loaded in ~4ms and ~8ms for the controller.

Answer (score 2):

Try to move this function into a service. Then register this service in twig as a global variable. config.yml:

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    globals:
      number_requests_service: %your_service_name%
```

Then in twig you can load it:

```
{{ number_request_service.renderSomething }}
```

If you need the user request in the service itself, then give them the request_stack in service configuration.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I think it's a good idea, in my case, I think I do not change, because finally, the main part of the time is for the debug toolbar. And if we remove it, it takes just few ms to generate it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem few day ago, and i solve it with a twig extension you can create it like a service and inject your entityManager to do your request and return a view. With this way Symfony2 isn't load a second time.